# How to add image view in between list view which populated from json?

Tags: android, json, listview

I need to add image view in between listview

we can apply with particular position for example

```
if(position == 10){


}
```

But in this case in that 10th position JSON data will not be populated so is there any other way to do achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listviews are arbitrary layouts. I recommend making a layout that includes a imageview that is normally "gone", and shows only in your "10" case.  You could also use a ViewSwitcher in your listview item layout.

create a listview_item.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="You'll fill this in with json"/>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:contentDescription="only show this image in exception case"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your adapter's onBind:

```
if(position == 10){
  view.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  view.findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
  view.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.GONE);
  TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
  tv.setText(jsonStrings[position]);
  tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```